# Limit of a sequence depending on a parameter

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

The problem given by our teacher during the class goes as follows: Determine the limit of a sequence $a_n$ depending on the parameter $p$ if $a_n=\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}-pn-1$.
**My attempt of solution**:
$$\lim{(\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}-pn-1)}=\lim{n\left(\sqrt{4+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{5}{n^2}}-p-\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\lim{n} \cdot \lim{\left(\sqrt{4+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{5}{n^2}}-p-\frac{1}{n}\right)}.$$
Now it's easy to see that all fractions under the second limit vanish and we are left with 
$\lim{n} \cdot \lim{(2-p)}$. $2-p$ is a constant value, and hence $\lim{(2-p)}=2-p$. The whole expression then becomes $$(2-p)\lim{n}.$$ Thus, for $p>2$ we get $-\infty$, and for $p<2$ the result is $+\infty$. The only unknown sitution happens for $p=2$, because we get an undefined "$0 \cdot \infty$". We've got to investigate this situation further. By plugging in $p=2$ to the original form and using a well-known technique, i.e. multiplying $\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}-(2n+1)$ by $$\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}+(2n+1)}{\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}+(2n+1)},$$
we get $\lim{\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}-(2n+1)}=-\frac{1}{4}$. And these are correct, according to the answer sheet in the textbook. **My teacher, however, claims that the method I used is invalid.** The problem is, I don't see any mistake here... Can you point it out for me?

Comment: You can't break one limit into two like you did. You can do this only if both limits exist.

Comment: The theorem in my textbook says: $\lim(a_n \pm b_n)=\lim a_n \pm \lim b_n$

Comment: Ok, but they do exist.

Comment: no, one of them tends to infinity

Comment: Right, so a limit in infinity isn't a limit? I always thought, that a limit doesn't exist in situation like $\lim (-1)^n$ or something like that

Comment: Re-read the definition of limit, infinity is not a number that can be used in that definition. It's OK to say the limit is equal to infinity but technically it does not exist and definitely we cannot apply properties of limits when one of the limits is infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see: $$\lim{(\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}-pn-1)}=\lim{\frac{(\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}-pn-1)(\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}+pn+1)}{\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}+pn+1}}=\lim{\frac{4n^2+3n+5-(pn+1)^2}{\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}+pn+1}}=\lim{\frac{n^2(4-p^2)+n(3-2p)+4}{\sqrt{4n^2+3n+5}+pn+1}}=\lim{\frac{n(4-p^2)+3-2p+\frac{4}{n}}{\sqrt{4+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{5}{n^2}}+p+\frac{1}{n}}}$$ From here it's clear than the limit won't exist if $4-p^2 \ne 0$.

If $p=2$, the limit exists ant it's equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$
if $p=-2$ the limit does not exist because the denominator becomes zero.